# How to translate the codes about blur detection with Opencv from C++ to java

Tags: java, opencv

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "iostream"

using namespace cv;

double contrast_measure( const Mat&img )
{
    Mat dx, dy;
    Sobel( img, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0, 3 );
    Sobel( img, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1, 3 );
    magnitude( dx, dy, dx );
    return sum(dx)[0];
}

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"lena.jpg";
    Mat src = imread( filename );

    if(src.data)
    {
        std::cout << "original image : " << contrast_measure( src ) / 1e3 << std::endl;

        for( int i =3; i < 80; i+=2 )
        {
            Mat blurred;
            GaussianBlur( src, blurred, Size(i,i), 0);
            imshow(  "blurred image", blurred );
            waitKey(200);
            std::cout << "blurred image  : " << contrast_measure( blurred ) / 1e3 << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am doing a project and a part is related to blur detection. The code above is trying to output the measured value of blurryness written by c++ . Since I am new to opencv. Can anyone translate the code to java please?

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: i have tried to rewrite the measure function first. and i am getting stuck with sobel , magnitude , and sumElems.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265834/995891 for the reason your question just gained a close vote.

Answer (score 2):

There are opencv methods, using the Java bindings, for gaussian blur:

```
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src, blurred, new Size(i,i),50);
```

& for Sobel

```
Imgproc.Sobel(src_gray, grad_x, depth, 1, 0, 3, skala, delta, Imgproc.BORDER_DEFAULT);
```

& for [magnitude](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.2/index.html?org/opencv/core/Core.html)

From that you basically rewrite your code in the same structure in JAVA.

Comment: Just as small correction: javacv is a 3rd party lib, what you are referring to is opencv java bindings